# Export default works, but export anything else does not in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am fairly new to ES6.

I am trying to call a function with two arguments:

```
export XYZ withFetching(noticeAPI)(promoIter)
```

and

```
export withFetching(noticeAPI)(promoIter)
```

It works when I do it as:

```
export default withFetching(noticeAPI)(promoIter)
```

The function looks like this:

```
const withFetching = (url) => (Comp) =>
```

Why does it work with the default keyword but not with any type of names?

Sorry if this is a dumb question about ES6, but I've tried every variation of the export syntax that I found on here with no luck.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
export default withFetching(noticeAPI)(promoIter);
```

is short for

```
const _invisibleVariable_ = withFetching(noticeAPI)(promoIter);
export { _invisibleVariable_ as default };
```

So given your example

```
export XYZ withFetching(noticeAPI)(promoIter)
```

assuming you want `XYZ` to be the name, you can do

```
const XYZ = withFetching(noticeAPI)(promoIter);
export { XYZ };
```

or

```
export const XYZ = withFetching(noticeAPI)(promoIter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi did you try like this ?

```js
export const XYZ = withFetching(noticeAPI)(promoIter);
```

And then importing it like this

```js
import { XYZ } form 'somepath';
```

Comment: I did try export const XYZ = withFetching(noticeAPI)(promoIter); at one point, and I get the error: Line 42:  Parsing error: Unexpected token on the export withFetching etc line

Comment: How about `export const XYZ = (noticeAPI, promoIter) => withFetching(noticeAPI)(promoIter)`

Comment: No error gets thrown with that, but when I try to use <XYZ /> after import in another component, console gives the error: Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child.